# how to enable stacktrace log in jboss soa 5.3 to get rid of Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace

Tags: jboss5.x, jboss-logging

i am using jboss 5.3 soa which runs on jboss as 5.1. 
while trying to access teiid client with admin user i am getting "Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.". Infact i get this error is few other places.
pls let mw know to enable more details loggin with stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed later 
Visit https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-3574